# Why my ViewPager preload back two page instead of current page and front page and back page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, preload

I'm sorry for my English, but i am so confused, why my ViewPager preload back two page, I know the VipwPager if current page is 1 then it will preload 0 and 2 page, but my ViewPager will preload 2 and 3 page, i don't know the reason why, please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You maybe use `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` in your code!
You can use

```
setOffscreenPageLimit(1)
```

or remove the code from your